# Visual Studio 2012: List of all Methods in class

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, resharper

In VS 2010, is there a way to see all the Methods in a docked window for the currently viewed class. Clicking the method would let me navigate to it.

This question is for design mode, while editing a class in the IDE.

I own Resharper, but don't see a way to see all the methods in a nice list as a feature.

Comment: have you looked at using Reflection..?

Comment: This is for design mode, while editing a class in the IDE.

Comment: you need to do this at runtime via Reflection..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`View -> Class View` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
You see the different classes on the top panel and the methods on the bottom panel.

Also, you have the method list on the top part of your tab:
[image]

Comment: This is probably as close as it will get. You can assign a keyboard shortcut to `View.SynchronizeClassView` to have the class view automatically jump to the right place.

Comment: But how can I get it to show the current class. I have a huge solution with hundreds of classes in dozens of projects. I need to quickly see 'where I am' in the current class.

Comment: @BahaiResearch.com I think the keyboard shortcut is as close as it will get. You could develop a Visual Studio Add On that automatically calls that when the current file selection changes, though.

Comment: I tried a couple of key combinations from Global and this shortcut would not work for me.

Answer (score 15):

If you have Resharper at your disposal as you indicate, you can use the File Structure window. It looks like this:

[image]

To open it, click Resharper, Windows, "File Structure". The window is dockable, and updates as your current file changes.

[image]

Comment: It's probably worth noting that this window is incredibly useful. You can use it for navigation, you can also drag items around in the window to reorder members in your code, and group them into regions if that's your style. The "Automatically scroll to source" option makes it easy to just click on things and automatically go to it in the source editor.

Answer (score 1):

You have VS 2012. This version has enancements in Solution Explorer.
If you expand a class file node you will see all classes.
And if you expand a class node you will see all its members.

See http://blog.wpfwonderland.com/2012/08/04/visual-studio-2012-tidbits-01-class-members-in-solution-explorer for an explanation.