# Is their any way to list functions names that are written .cs file in visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, methods, visual-studio-2013, code-navigation

I want to know that is their any way to list all the functions names that are written in my c# .cs code in visual studio 2013.  I know that if I know function names than by using peek definition or using f12, I can jump to that function definition, but what about the case when my code file contains number of function and I have to list all function declaration list so that I can easily search to function I am looking at and jump to its definition in visual studio 2013.

For Example- Suppose i have written a c# code(Code length > 4000 lines) that contains multiple method names and if i save my file and after sometime i again open it. Now this time forgot the name of my method then, is their any way i can list all the function declaration of that file in visual studio 2013, so that i can easily jump to that function.

Plz let me know!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819519/visual-studio-window-which-shows-list-of-methods

Comment: As @MickyD's link notes, there's already drop-down lists at the top of the code editor window that let you browse a list of members.  If you have multiple classes in the same file you'll need to select which one to browse, but otherwise functionality close to what you're looking to do is already built in to Visual Studio.  The Object Browser would be another way to do the same thing.

Comment: [Visual Studio 2012: List of all Methods in class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13904806/visual-studio-2012-list-of-all-methods-in-class) is another (near-)duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a drop down box in the navigation bar just above the text editor in the upper right that lists the methods in the current file. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819519/visual-studio-window-which-shows-list-of-methods) answer for more info.

Comment: This should be in comment

Comment: I agree, but I don’t have enough reputation to comment on questions :(

Comment: This is incorrect, it lists all members of the current class, regardless of what file they are in.