# Exporting Selenium Test Method list to a text file

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm having some trouble generating a `.txt` file with all the Test Methods that my project has.

We are using .NET and different classes for the tests, maybe this screenshot may help:

[image]

Is there any way to export these methods to a `.txt`?

Comment: Sorry, im new, and my image doesnt get uploaded by my falt.

Comment: If you're using an IDE I'd suggest going to a search engine and try to find for your IDE's way to get a list of test method names of a given class. If you're using a text editor like Sublime or Atom, you could use Find option and use a search expression that catches some point of all test methods, and then choose a "find all" option, to select all lines and copy them to a text file.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2017, the only way that I found is using the ReSharper, but this can't be the solution right now.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819519/visual-studio-window-which-shows-list-of-methods

Are you able to select with the cursor the displayed methods from the navigation bar dropdown?

Comment: Yes I do, like on his print.

Comment: Hey, take a look at the question that I've marked this as a duplicate of; and if you can't figure out how to make that work I can translate it into c#

Comment: This solved the problem, thank you @Rescis