# not able to navigate between events of a object with dropdown box like visual studio 2019 in VS 2022 >

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I am not sure did they change it the way we can do it or is there any simpler way or they actually removed the option and limited us to use code instead

in vs 2019 if we double click the button we directly went to click event of a button and then from the upper right dropdown box we can easily move to any other event of a current object like double click or mouse over etc which automatically created the event handling SUB
but I am not able to do it in the VS 2022 so what happened with it?
as you can see in the attached images

[image]

Comment: Select the control you want to navigate to in the drop down to the left of the one you are looking for events in.

Comment: well, that will help but why it's not automatically selected like older versions? even if we move caret between different events in code editor it selects the event in the dropbox automatically

Comment: we cant select events i tried that it takes us to designer form where the object is created and defined still we cant directly jump to other events of the object e.g keydown, mouse over, got focus,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug has been fixed in the latest version of the VS 2022 as per below post. Just tested and seems to be working as it used to!

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/event-drop-down-menu-in-the-upper-right-corner-of/1579215

Comment: oh i am glad that they found it I thought that's and discontinued feature may b, thanks for the info I will reedit my answer

Answer (score 3):

I'm truly hoping that it's a bug in VS2022 because I'm really missing this function too. I've found a lot of topics in the official discussions and feeds and it seems that different older versions have the same issue, but they have already patched them. No info about 17.0.x version. :( I'll investigate further. Please report if somebody find a working solution.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Options->Text Editor->(your language) and enable "Navigation Bar".

Previously answered here:
[Visual Studio window which shows list of methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819519/visual-studio-window-which-shows-list-of-methods/2819532)

Comment: i appreciate the answer but my question was slightly different, I have the navigation bar already but what I am asking is that when we open an object or we directly go to an method of an object in earlier versions if you notice the navigation automatically goes to current method but in vs 2022 you have to select the object first in the navigation and then you have to select the other method you will to open navigation doesn't select he object automatically like earlier versions e.g vs 2019

Comment: Oh I see now. I've just tried this with C++ and C#, and it seems to work for both cases on my setup. It might be something specific to VB..?

Comment: well it could be as it was okay till vs 2019 but in vs 2022 vb.net its not navigate automatically

Answer (score 0):

well finally I found the answer to my question with thanks to mrtn

Microsoft finally found the bug and fixed the Asked Issue in question, so New update will solve this problem that was a bug from VS 2022

Additionally, I want to mention there is another way to create/edit Object's Events from Design view
Go to the design view and then click the Button with Lightning icon, a list of Events will Appear, and then go for the desired event and double click to add the event or edit it
[image: Event Button and events list]