# What is the keyboard shortcut to methods dropdown at the top of Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

What is the keyboard shortcut to methods dropdown at the top of Visual Studio 2015?

[image: VS Editor]

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194908/visual-studio-keyboard-shortcut-for-method-name-combobox

Comment: WOW!! tnx @SergeyVlasov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer thanks to `@SergeyVlasov`.

> Thanks to Jeff's Keyboard Shortcut Summary Macro, I discovered that
>   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> is mapped to a **MovetoNavigationBar** command, which pops me
>   into the "Class Name combobox." Add a tab and I'm in the Method Name
>   combobox.
>
> [Answer Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1239254/4107888)